# configuration command for bringing python import statements to top of the script upon saving in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am configuring my vscode for running python scripts. I have configured black, sort, and flake8 for formatting and linting. The problem I am facing is, I have many import statements inside my python script (not at the top), which I wish to bring to the top without cut and pasting manually. Please share if there are any tools or configurations available for vscode, to help me in that field.

```
# Original code    
import pandas as pd

print("Hello world")
{some other code block}

import numpy as np
{rest of the code block}
```

The way I want the tool or setting to format automatically

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print("Hello world")

{some other code block}

{rest of the code block}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: right click the file and select Format document

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `autopep8` formatting.

```
"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
```

Comment: @Krishnakant Achary M hello friend, does it work?